# Authentication of html5 web site

Tags: html, security, authentication

I have HTML5 pages developed for an application, I have bundled it as a war file and deployed on WAS CE.

Now I want to implement authentication & authorization to the application, so that only authorized users can view the web site.

How can I implement *

> authentication & authorization of the html5 page resource

*s like we secure Java web applications using JAAS or Spring Security..

Regards
Sree..

Answer (score 1):

HTML5/JavaScript is entirely client side.  There for this code cannot authenticate the client. JAAS or Spring Security's Session handler can verify that a client has been authenticated.  Then on the server side you can deny the html5 client access to resources based on their authentication credentials stored by the session handler.

Comment: Any example or tutorial for that? I have exactly the same problem how to make HTML5 - Rest application safe.

Comment: @Sami every web app works like this,  unless it was written by someone who doesn't understand the basics of security.

Answer (score 1):

On the server side you can use XML to define what users are allowed to view what resources.

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Stuff like that.